Why does earning an assignment grade with a percent higher than your current average raise the average?
An overall average grade is the total points earned divided by the total points possible.
If I have a 75% average in the class, or a $300/400,$ why does getting 75% or above on the next assignment bring up this average?
I wrote: $$\frac{a+x}{b+y} > \frac{a}{b}$$ $$ab+bx > ab+ay$$ $$bx > ay$$ $$x > \frac{a}{b}y.$$ Is this correct, or is there another simpler way?

You could approach this problem by trying to show that $\frac{a + x}{b + y} - \frac{a}{b}$ is greater than zero. First, add the fractions by multiplying through by denominators. Second, ignore the denominator because it is positive and does not affect the sign. You will end up with numerator $bx-ay$ which you want to show is positive. Divide by $by$, and use the fact that $x/y > a/b$.

75% or above on the next assignment If you got exactly 75%, then surely the average would not change?  Did you mean to say "above 75%" ?

You should always define the variables you use in a proof. More importantly, your reasoning starts by assuming that the average after the new assignment is greater than the current average, to conclude that your grade in the new assignment was larger than the average. This is not correct, since you want to prove the converse.

Your average now is $c$. You earn a grade $x\ge c$ on an additional assignment. What is your new average? If there were $p$ points possible total up to now and then $q$ points additionally, your new average will be given by the weighted average
$$\frac{pc + qx}{p+q} \ge \frac{pc+qc}{p+q} = \frac{(p+q)c}{p+q}=c.$$

The variable c woks especially well here because 75% is a C.

@mathlander LOL. Traditionally, yes.

You can do it by reversing the argument. Your computations show how the argument should go.
Assume $x,y,a,b \gt 0$ and that $\frac xy\gt \frac ab$ then multiply by $by\gt 0$ $$bx\gt ay$$Next add $ab$ to each side $$ab+bx\gt ab + ay; b(a+x)\gt a(b+y)$$Now divide by $b(b+y)\gt 0$ to get $$\frac {a+x}{b+y}\gt \frac ab$$
This way you work from the given data (latest score greater than previous average) to the desired conclusion - the current average is greater than the previous average.

Let $\bar x$ be the average of $n$ numbers. Then $$\bar x=\frac{x_1+\dots +x_n}{n}\implies n\bar x=x_1+\dots +x_n$$
If a new value $x_{n+1}\gt \bar x$ is added to the list of numbers then the new average is $$\bar y=\frac{x_1+\dots +x_n+x_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{n\bar x+x_{n+1}}{n+1}\gt\frac{n\bar x+\bar x}{n+1}=\frac{\bar x(n+1)}{n+1}=\bar x$$
EDIT:
Ted raises a good point. Suppose the grades are not worth the same.
Suppose there are $n$ assignments worth $w_1,\dots w_n$ points each and suppose each assignment gives a grade of $\frac{g_i}{s_i}$ where $s_i$ is the scale. For example, if $s_1=100$ and $g_1=80$, then $\frac{g_1}{s_1}=\frac{4}{5}$. To make the notation simpler, let's make $\frac{g_i}{s_i}=f_i$, i.e. the fraction of the total points available for assignment $i$.
Then our total grade is $$\frac{f_1w_1+\dots f_nw_n}{w_1+\dots w_n}$$
Our averge after $k$ assignments is $$\bar g = \frac{f_1w_1+\dots f_kw_k}{w_1+\dots w_k}$$
If $f_{k+1}\gt\bar g$ then the new average is $$\bar h=\frac{f_1w_1+\dots f_kw_k+f_{k+1}w_{k+1}}{w_1+\dots w_{k+1}}=\frac{\bar g(w_1+\dots w_k)+f_{k+1}w_{k+1}}{w_1+\dots w_{k+1}}\\\gt\frac{\bar g(w_1+\dots w_k)+\bar gw_{k+1}}{w_1+\dots w_k}=\frac{\bar g(w_1+\dots w_{k+1})}{w_1+\dots w_{k+1}}=\bar g$$

You’re assuming each and every assignment/exam carries the same weight in the class.

@TedShifrin That is correct. I didn't see anything in the question that suggested otherwise.

@TedShifrin I've addressed the case when the grades are weighted differently. The notation is not as clean but the idea is exactly the same.

@JohnDouma  The OP's first sentence defines their "average" grade; this computation tells us that it is a weighted average (every point has the same weight) rather than a simple average (every test has the same weight).

@ryang That wasn't clear to me. For example, suppose there are four assignments worth $100$ points each. If the student aces the first three, we wouldn't say that is average is $\frac{300}{400}=75%$. If that is the case, then the problem is trivial because anything above zero points would raise that number.

@ryang I understood that example by Ted's comment. I believe I addressed that in my second solution.

It isn't really necessary to consider weights. If, for instance, there are two tests, one weighted 2/5 and the other 3/5, we could just pretend there are five tests, and the student's percentage on the first two pretend tests are the same as their score on the first real test, and for the last three pretend tests, the same as the second real tests.  Even if a teacher wanted to be silly and have non-rational weights, for any set of weights on a finite number of questions, for a finite number of final grades, there is some rational set of weights that gives the same final grades in all cases.

Also, instead of have $f_iw_i$, you could just have $r_i$, where $r_i$ is the number of received points.


If I have a 75% average in the class, or a 300/400,
why does getting 75% or above on the next assignment bring up this average?

Getting exactly 75% doesn't bring up your average. A basic property of averages is that adding another numbers that is the same as the average of the previous numbers results in the same overall average. So let's says you have four tests of 100 points each, and you average 75% over the first three tests. Getting 75 points on the last test will result in your average remaining 75%.
Getting more than the average will result in your average going up because you got as much as the average, plus more. For instance, if you get 78 points, then that means that you got the 75 points you needed to keep your average the same, plus three extra points. Those three extra points will raise your average over 75%. That is, 78 is more than 75, 75 keeps your average at 75%, therefore 78 makes your average more than 75%.

The point of the average is that $n$ scores with average $\bar x$ are worth the same as $n$ scores of $\bar x$, that is
$$x_1+\cdots+x_n=\underbrace{\bar x+\cdots+\bar x}_{n\text{ times}}.$$
(Really, this is the definition of average: you can easily deduce the formula, but the reason behind the formula is that this is the relationship you want.)
Now it follows that
$$x_1+\cdots+x_n+\bar x=\underbrace{\bar x+\cdots+\bar x}_{n+1\text{ times}},$$
so getting exactly equal to the average on the next assignment will not change the average. Since increasing any score increases the average, doing better than the average on the next assignment will bring the average up.

If $\frac{x}{y}>\frac{a}{b}>0,$ with $y,b>0,$ then
$$\frac{a+x}{b+y} > \frac{a+\frac{ay}{b}}{b+y} $$
$$ = \frac{a\left(1+\frac{y}{b}\right)}{b\left(1+\frac{y}{b}\right)} $$
$$ = \frac{a}{b}.$$

The previous very good answers all expand on the OPs algebraic solution and provide good reasoning why the initial claim is true. We can intuitively see this reason as:
Suppose your class has a student, Steady Eddie, who makes exactly 75% on every assignment. If you also have a 75%, then you and Eddie have earned the same total number of points -- even if you got there in very different ways (some better that Eddie, some not). On the next assignment, Eddie again makes his same old 75%. If you do better than Eddie on this assignment, you have more points than him and so your class average must now be higher than his.

What you wrote is correct. I don't see any simpler way than what you did in your computations; the other answers suggest methods that are equivalent or more complicated.
One possible nitpick is that the statement of the problem says "75% or above", so you should work with $\geq$ signs rather than $>$ if you want to convert that statement to formulas. But it is a minor detail.


State the premise:

$x_{n+1} > \frac{\sum_i x_i}{n} $

Add the sum to both sides:

$\implies x_{n+1} + \sum_i x_i> \frac{\sum_i x_i}{n} + \sum_i x_i$

Multiply both sides by n

$\implies  n(x_{n+1} + \sum_i x_i)> \sum_i x_i + n\sum_i x_i = (n+1)\sum_i x_i  $

Divide across

$\implies \frac{x_{n+1} + \sum_i x_i}{n+1} > \frac{\sum_i x_i}{n}$
There's a similar version with weights.

State the premise:

$p_{n+1} > \frac{\sum_i p_i w_i}{\sum_i w_i} $
2 Multiply both steps by the new weight:
$\implies p_{n+1} w_{n+1} > w_{n+1} \frac{\sum_i p_i w_i}{\sum_i w_i} $

Add the sum to both sides:

$\implies p_{n+1} w_{n+1} + \sum_i p_i w_i > w_{n+1} \frac{\sum_i p_i w_i}{\sum_i w_i} + \sum_i p_i w_i = (w_{n+1} +  \sum_i w_i)\frac{\sum_i p_i w_i}{\sum_i w_i}$

Divide across

$\implies  \frac{p_{n+1} w_{n+1} + \sum_i p_i w_i}{(w_{n+1} +  \sum_i w_i)}  > \frac{\sum_i p_i w_i}{\sum_i w_i}$

It is more insightful to think in terms of what the average actually is. By definition, the average $m$ is the unique number that satisfies
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-m)^2 = \min_c \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-c)^2\,.$$
(If you know calculus, then this follows from differentiating with respect to $c$ and using the second derivative test. Otherwise, it is an exercise in completing the square.)
You can check that this implies
$$m = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\,.$$
This implies the average centers the data in the sense that if $m$ is the average of $x_1,\dots,x_n$, then $$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-m) = 0\,.$$ From this, it is clear that unless $x_{n+1} = m$, the new average $\tilde m$ is necessarily not equal to $m$.  If we now choose $x_{n+1}>m$, then $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(x_i-m)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-m)^2+(x_{n+1}-m)^2\,.$$ Can we choose $c$ that does better, that is, can we choose $c$ so that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-c)^2+(x_{n+1}-c)^2< \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-m)^2+(x_{n+1}-m)^2\,?$$
As we have noted, we necessarily must choose $c\neq m$. If we choose $c<m$, then we end up with $$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-c)^2 >\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-m)^2\,,\quad (x_{n+1}-c)^2 > (x_{n+1}-m)^2\,. $$
Thus, we see that choosing $c<m$ in fact leads to performance worse than $c = m$. Since $c=m$ is not possible, we must have $c>m$, that is, the new sample mean must be larger than $m$ if the new data point $x_{n+1}>m$.

I don't find this answer "more insightful". The question is elementary and calls for an elementary answer, which the OP has almost provided.

A simpler way to say   “the unique number that satisfies
$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-m)^2 = \min_c \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-c)^2,$” is “the unique number $c$ that minimizes $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-c)^2$”.
